# Python wrong SSL version using requests

Tags: python

I have been struggling with this problem since I installed python on a new PC.
Basically, I have the `https` request:

```
import requests
import ssl

proxies = {
    'https': "https://myproxyhere"
}

r = requests.get('https://example.com', proxies=proxies, timeout=10)     
print(r.text)
```

On the other PC it works fine, but on this one it gives that error:

````
```(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)')))```
````

I had `openssl 1.1.1h` installed and `python 3.9` had `openssl` version `1.1.1g`. However, I downgraded my `openssl` to `1.1.1g`, and still the error persists, I'm not able to do SSL requests, using proxies.

Keep in mind that the proxies are not the cause, as i have the same exact piece of code working fine on my other laptop, however i bought a Windows Surface Pro and when i did this fresh install, im not able to make this work. Ive tried everything so far, from trying other versions of openssl and python.

Does someone have a clue on how to fix this?

Full Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gonca\Desktop\debug.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://example.com', proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
  File "C:\Users\gonca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gonca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gonca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gonca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gonca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)')))
```

Edit:
For people that face this error, the solution was down-grading the requests module, it was bugged.

Comment: This is a protocol version issue, not a library version issue. Sometimes it means one side is not actually using SSL at all, and the other side is trying to parse something that isn't a SSL handshake as if it were one.

Comment: "Using proxies" is a critical note, and it would be very helpful if you said more about it. What values are being passed in the parameter `proxies`? If your client is trying to connect to a proxy via an encrypted connection where the proxy server expects an unencrypted connection, or the inverse... well, that's something I'd want to start by looking at.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Hey, that part is not the issue, because on my other laptop that i had openssl older version and the python 3.85 it  works fine and there is not the error of wrong version. Only on this new computer where i did a fresh install of python and openssl. Ive tried everything so far, reinstalling python , other python version, installing other openssl, and no luck. PS: The code is exactly the same on both machines.

Comment: If this is a Windows-y machine, I'd worry about one but not the other having something like an antivirus trying to do a man-in-the-middle attack on your outbound connections. This error message has nothing at all to do with software versions.

Comment: (btw, the question says "not able to do SSL requests, using proxies" -- I read that to mean that you're only unable to do SSL requests _when you're using proxies_. How should I have read it instead?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You should read that has like, i can do requests without using proxies, but when i use proxies with https it goes on that error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i added the full traceback and the code im using to simplify the understanding

Comment: if the problem only happens when you're using proxies with HTTPS, then why do you think it's unreasonable when I suggest that you're trying to send a HTTPS request to a proxy that only supports HTTP? If it's because you think both systems are using the same proxy... well, it's worth investigating to make sure that's actually true, and it's not something like an antivirus putting its own proxy in the way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I solved it, was the requests module that was bugged, i downgraded and it works fine.

Comment: @Goncalo - can you say a bit more about the Requests module being "bugged"?  I assume you mean that it was a bug in the Requests code that was causing your trouble.  Do you have any sort of reference to documentation for the issue?  I ask because we use Requests to talk HTTPS sometimes through a proxy, so I'd appreciate whatever information you can provide in case we have something similar come up.

Comment: @CryptoFool for me just updated to Python 3.9.1 x64 on Windows 10 and latest requests 2.25.1 I had to revert to requests 2.24.0 to get things working.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in requests-2.25.1. I have to downgrade to 2.24.0

```
pip install requests==2.24.0
```